# send a voice message as attachment with applozic android

Tags: android, chat, voice, applozic

i'm working with **applozic** api, and i can't find in the documentation how to send a **voice message** as attachment.

```
import com.applozic.mobicomkit.api.conversation.MobiComConversationService;

 public void sendMessage(Message message)        
 {             
   ...        
 }

new MobiComConversationService(activity).sendMessage(new     
Message("contact@applozic.com", "hello test"));


 public synchronized List<Message> getLatestMessagesGroupByPeople()        
 {            
  ...         
 }

 public List<Message> getMessages(String userId, Long startTime, Long endTime)        
 {            
  ...           
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to send a voice message:

1. Direct way:
   Create message object and set the userId whom you want to send message and set the file path of voice message file, user content Type Message.ContentType.AUDIO_MSG.getValue().

   ```
   Message message = new Message();
   message.setTo("userId");//Replace userId with user whom u want send a audio message
   List<String> filePathsList = new ArrayList<String>();
   filePathsList.add(filePath);//set the file path where the audio file is stored
   message.setFilePaths(filePathsList);
   message.setContentType(Message.ContentType.AUDIO_MSG.getValue());
   new MobiComConversationService(context).sendMessage(message);
   ```
2. UI toolkit:
   Click attachment option icon --> select Audio --> record the voice and send voice message.

[image]